# Load a different page in nuxt at runtime based on the parameters in the route

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

We have a scenario in which a different page is required to be loaded based on whether parts of the route has parameters that are valid and that can be determined at run-time.

Consider the following example:
Request to `http://example.com/param1/param2`

If param1 is a valid product identifier (can be determined by an API call to another service) the product page loads or its considered a category and Category Page is loaded.

Considering Nuxt uses static routes mostly and the list of products are dynamic, is there a hook where you can execute custom code to load a different page ?

Answer (score 1):

Cant you create  _product page
like described in nuxt docs:

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#dynamic-routes

And in your code make something like:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <nuxt-child />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    asyncData({route, params, redirect}) {
         //use route
        console.log(route.params.slug)
        //directly use params
        console.log(params.slug)
        redirect(`/`);
    },
};
</script>
```

or use `mounted()` hook if you are creating SPA

Comment: The issue with this is that it will cause a 302 redirect and we have strict SEO requirement to keep the URL the same.
What we are having to do is create a Single page of entry and that loads a different component based on the parameters. Looking for a higher level to do it at.